# TextView - setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback how create ActionMode.Callback for when the text is selected to many TextView

Tags: android, textview, custom-controls

I have  several **TextView** in my systems and most of them I have to call my custom `ActionMode.Callback`.

The question is how do I create a  TextView with custom `ActionMode.Callback`?

today my code is that way

```
mTxOne.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new MarkTextSelectionActionModeCallback());
 mTxTwo.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new MarkTextSelectionActionModeCallback());
...
```

Comment: Can you be more clear?

Comment: I am sorry. my problem is to create class that extends from textview and use my custom ActionMode.Callback, thus will not be necessary to call mtextview.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback (new MarkTextSelectionActionModeCallback ()) for each textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class TextViewA extends TextView {

    @Override
    protected void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu);
        setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new MarkTextSelectionActionModeCallback());
    }



public TextViewA(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public TextViewA(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context,attrs);
}
public TextViewA(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
```

Here the xml

```
 <RelativeLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <br.com.vrbsm.textviewexample.TextViewA
      android:id="@+id/textView2" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textIsSelectable="true"
      android:textSize="12dp"
      />
</RelativeLayout>
```

here main

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
//  
    private TextViewA textview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        textview = (TextViewA)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textview.setText("Android is crazy");

    }


public class MarkTextSelectionActionModeCallback implements Callback {
.
.
.}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 public class CustomActionModeTextView extends TextView{

       //...implement your constructors as you may want to use...//
       @Override
       public ActionMode.Callback getCustomSelectionActionModeCallback (){
          return new MarkTextSelectionActionModeCallback();
        }


 }
```

Create your own `TextView` and override the method [getCustomSelectionActioModeCallback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getCustomSelectionActionModeCallback()) to return always an instance of your custom action mode callback. This way you don't have to set it everytime in your views.

**Remember**

- Use your custom class in your XML layout files;
- When casting it, do the cast to your custom class and not `TextView`;
- You may wanna consider keeping a reference to your custom callback in your class. You could initialize it during some `constructor` and return it in the `get` method. This would be just to avoid creating new instances on every method call.

Comment: thanks my friend, but the method that is called is startActionMode(), so my code stayed that way....  @Override
 public ActionMode startActionMode(Callback callback) {
  return super.startActionMode(new MarkTextSelectionActionModeCallback());
 }

Comment: Please, post your own answer here and mark it as the correct one to help others :)